# Python groupby nested dictionary is ambiguous in aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregation

I am currently working on my thesis and facing some problems in a groupby function I want to do. I am trying to find out someone's total purchase amount, average purchase amount, purchase count, how many products bought in total and the average value per product.

The data looks like thise:

```
    id  purchase_amount price_products  #_products
0   123 30              20.00           2
2   123 NaN             10.00           NaN
3   124 50.00           25.00           3
4   124 NaN             15.00           NaN
5   124 NaN             10.00           NaN
```

My code looks like this:

```
df.groupby('id')[['purchase_amount','price_products','#_products']].agg(total_purchase_amount=('purchase_amount','sum'),average_purchase_amount=('purchase_amount','mean'),times_purchased=('#_products','count'),total_amount_products_purchased=('price_products','count'),average_value_products=('price_products','mean'))
```

But I get the following error:

> SpecificationError: nested dictionary is ambiguous in aggregation

I cannot seem to find what I am doing wrong, hopefully someone can help me!

Comment: Work's fine for me ``pandas==1.0.0``, what is the version of pandas you'r using ?

Comment: Thank you for trying. My pandas version is 0.25.1

Comment: works fine in version `'0.25.1'` for me

Comment: This same error happened to me when running e.g. `df.groupby('id')[vars].agg({'n': "count", 'mean': "mean"})` whenever `vars` is a list of variable names with just ONE element. I.e., when `vars` is a list with SEVERAL elements, the aggregation works fine, o.w. it breaks with the same error "nested dictionary is ambiguous in aggregation" (pandas `0.22.0`). Note that current latest version of pandas is 1.2.4, where the above syntax is no longer accepted. Instead use `df.groupby('id')[vars].agg(["count", "mean"])`, and things work fine even when `vars` has one element (also true on `0.22.0`).

Answer (score 0):

Do like this for all calculations

```
df.groupby('id')['purchase_amount'].agg({'total_purchase_amount':'sum'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have several variables to aggregate, I would suggest using the following form of aggregation:

`df.groupby('id')[<variables-list>].agg([<statistics-list>])`

For example:

`df_agg = df.groupby('id')[['purchase_amount','price_products','#_products']].agg(["count", "mean", "sum"])`

This will create a column-wise multi-level output data frame `df_agg` that looks like:

```
    purchase_amount             price_products          #_products          
              count  mean   sum          count mean sum      count mean  sum
id                                                                          
123               1  30.0  30.0              2   15  30          1  2.0  2.0
124               1  50.0  50.0              3   17  51          1  3.0  3.0
```

You can then refer to a particular entry in the output data frame using the multi-index as follows:

`df_agg['purchase_amount']['mean']`

```
id
123    30.0
124    50.0
Name: mean, dtype: float64
```

or if you want e.g. all the means, use the cross-sectional method `xs()`:

`df_agg.xs('mean', axis=1, level=1)`

```
     purchase_amount  price_products  #_products
id                                              
123             30.0              15         2.0
124             50.0              17         3.0
```

Note: presumably, the above piece of code will make Python compute more statistics than needed, as is the case in your example. But this may not be an issue in certain contexts, and it has the advantage that the code is shorter and generalizable to any set and number of (numeric and float) variables to aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in an organized way using a dictionary for your aggregation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[123, 30, 20, 2],
                   [123, np.nan, 10, np.nan],
                   [124, 50, 25, 3],
                   [124, np.nan, 15, np.nan],
                   [124, np.nan, 10, np.nan]],
                  columns=['id', 'purchase_amount', 'price_products', 'num_products']
                  )

agg_dict = {
    'purchase_amount': [np.sum, np.mean],
    'num_products': [np.count_nonzero],
    'price_products': [np.count_nonzero, np.mean],
}

print(df.groupby('id').agg(agg_dict))
```

output:

```
    purchase_amount        num_products price_products           
                sum  mean count_nonzero  count_nonzero       mean
id                                                               
123            30.0  30.0           2.0              2  15.000000
124            50.0  50.0           3.0              3  16.666667
```